# HAs YOU BRaIN CoNFUSION?

Tags: language

> CaN YOU AsCErTaIn WHAt IS UNUSUAl As CoNCeRnS ThIS PArAgRaPH?
>   SURe, YOU CaN NoTiCe OBVIOUS AlTeRaTiONS In ClAsSiC PHRaSe CHoICeS.
>   WHY UPPEr CaSe SO OFTeN?
>   HAs OP BRaIn CoNFUSiON?
>   HAs YOU BRaIN CoNFUSION?
>   ONCe KNoWN, IS OBVIOUS, YEs?

---

<sub>To clarify, the odd capitalization is *not* the unusual point we seek. There's a very particular reason for the capital letters and *that* is what must be found. If this ends up being too broad because people are clever and find things that fit I hadn't considered, I'll post what I was thinking of and close the question myself.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For one,

> all capital letters signify the start of a chemical element's symbol. E.g. "CaN" being calcium and nitrogen (Ca, N).

Is the intended answer something more sophisticated?

Comment: Probably correct.

Comment: Yep, that would explain why OP does not use "do" / "does" (no D).

Comment: Nothing too sophisticated, no. All the words can be made using chemical symbols on the periodic table.

Comment: @EngineerToast It must have taken forever to find possible phrases!

Comment: @Block Actually, it wasn't too bad. I dumped [this list](http://www.nandor.org/math/chemwords/spelllist.htm) into Excel, added a `MATCH` function on another sheet, and started trying possibilities. It is very frustrating forming sentences without words like `a`, `at`, `the`, and `it`.